# The specified value "[object Object]" cannot be parsed, or is out of range

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a currency converter application with React but on my console, after typing in a number in my input, I get a warning saying "The specified value "[object Object]" cannot be parsed, or is out of range."

Here is the relevant code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [currencyState, setCurrencyState] = useState('');

  const dollar = 'Dollar';
  const shekel = 'Shekel';

  const handleDollarChange = (value) => {
    setValue({ value });
    setCurrencyState('Dollar');
  };

  const handleShekelChange = (value) => {
    setValue({ value });
    setCurrencyState('Shekel');
  };

  const val = value;
  const currency = currencyState;
  const dollars = currency === 'Dollar' ? tryConvert(val, toShekels) : val;
  const shekels = currency === 'Shekel' ? tryConvert(val, toDollars) : val;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CurrencyInput
        value={dollars}
        currency={dollar}
        onChange={handleDollarChange}
      />
      <CurrencyInput
        value={shekels}
        currency={shekel}
        onChange={handleShekelChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the original CurrencyInput code:

```
const CurrencyInput = (props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Your currency has been converted');
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.onChange(e.target.value);
  };

  const value = props.value;
  const currency = props.currency;

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Enter {currency}s: &nbsp;
          <input type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [currencyState, setCurrencyState] = useState('');

  const dollar = 'Dollar';
  const shekel = 'Shekel';

  const handleDollarChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    setCurrencyState('Dollar');
  };

  const handleShekelChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    setCurrencyState('Shekel');
  };

  const val = value;
  const currency = currencyState;
  const dollars = currency === 'Dollar' ? tryConvert(val, toShekels) : val;
  const shekels = currency === 'Shekel' ? tryConvert(val, toDollars) : val;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CurrencyInput
        value={dollars}
        currency={dollar}
        onChange={handleDollarChange}
      />
      <CurrencyInput
        value={shekels}
        currency={shekel}
        onChange={handleShekelChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You’re calling `setValue({ value })`, which passes an *object* containing a single key `value`. You probably meant to write `setValue(value)` instead.